# How do I filter an LDAP query for groups containing a specific user?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

How do I filter an Active Directory LDAP query to groups containing the authenticated/bound user (or any user at all)? This works fine:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=*))
>>> lots of results
```

But I can't go any more detail:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=*S*))
>>> nothing
```

The MSDN mentions using a filter like this:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x))
```

But even ignoring the *crazy hyper magic number* involved in that, I always get 0 results when I try to filter with that (even replacing `cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x` with my own distinguishedName, even replacing it with `*`).

Comment: The MSDN Search Filter Syntax page linked in @JPBlanc's answer below *lists* the crazy hyper magic number, but it doesn't *explain* it. The *explanation* is that it's a node in the obscure, worldwide [OID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier) standard administered by ISO and ITU-T, of which LDAP is [one of the few prominent uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier#Usage). See http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?tree=1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 for a structural breakdown of each number's significance.

Answer (score 11):

You need the full DN of  the user i.e

```
(&(member=CN=Your Name,OU=Your OU,DC=company,DC=com)(objectClass=group))
```

take note you cannot use * in this one

Comment: "I always get 0 results when I try to filter with that (**even replacing `cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x` with my own distinguishedName**"

Answer (score 5):

So the *crazy hyper magic number* involved in recursive search is explained in [Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To find in one search (recursively) all the groups that "user1" is a member of:

- Set the base to the groups container DN; for example root DN (dc=dom,dc=fr)
- Set the scope to subtree
- Use the following filter: `(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x)`

explicited using LDIFDE.EXE the command line tool included in Windows Server it gives:

```
ldifde -f user1Grps.ldf -d "dc=societe,dc=local" -r "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=user1,ou=Monou,dc=societe,dc=local)"
```

If you are running that on a W2K8 or W2K8 R2 server be careful to run as administrator.

If you are programming in C# you can use:

```
/* Retreiving a principal context
 */
Console.WriteLine("Retreiving a principal context");
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT:389", "dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "PWD");


/* Look for all the groups a user belongs to
 */
UserPrincipal aUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "user1");
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> a =  aUser.GetAuthorizationGroups();

foreach (GroupPrincipal gTmp in a)
{
  Console.WriteLine(gTmp.Name);    
}
```