# Use ldap3 to query all active directory groups a user belongs to

Tags: windows, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I have no problem to query the domain user from active directory with this query

```
from ldap3 import ObjectDef, AttrDef, Reader, Entry, Attribute, OperationalAttribute
import ldap3

person = ObjectDef('inetOrgPerson')
s = ldap3.Server('myad.com')
c = ldap3.Connection(s, user = 'myuser', password = 'mypassword')

ldap3.Reader(c, person, '(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=myuser))', 'dc=mydomain,dc=com').search()
```

however, this query returns empty list of groups the user belongs to, how to make it work?

```
ldap3.Reader(c, person, '(&(objectCategory=group)(member=myuser))', 'dc=mydomain,dc=com').search()
```

I use [ldap3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/abstraction.html#overview). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051212/304319) helped me:

I need the **full** DN of the user returned from the first query, so this works:

```
ldap3.Reader(c, person, '(&(member=CN=myuser_in_full_name,OU=xxx,OU=xxxxxx,DC=mydomain,DC=com)(objectClass=group))', 'dc=mydomain,dc=com').search()
```